# Log normal distribution - Where am I wrong?

Tags: calculus, probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $X$ be a R.V whose pdf is given by 
$$f(x)=p\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right)+
(1-p)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)$$

clearly $X\sim pN(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+(1-p)N(\mu_2,\sigma_2^2)=N(p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2,p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2)$

therefore ***$\kappa=E(e^X)-1=e^{p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2+\frac{1}{2}(p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2)}-1$.***

However, if I let $Y=e^X$, then 
Let $G(y)$ be the cdf of $Y$, then 
$G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(e^X<y)=p(X<\ln(y))=F_X(\ln(y))$
there fore $g(y)=f(\ln(y))\frac{1}{y}$
so 
the pdf  $g(y)$ of $Y$ is given by

$$g(y)=p\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(y)-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2} \right) + (1-p) \frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(y)-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)$$

i.e $Y=p\times \mathrm{logNormal}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+(1-p)\times \mathrm{logNormal} (\mu_2,\sigma_1^2)$

where $\mathrm{logNormal}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ means a log-normal distribution.

hence ***$\kappa=E(Y)-1=pE(\mathrm{logNormal}(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2))+(1-p) E(\mathrm{logNormal} (\mu_2,\sigma_2^2))=
pe^{\mu_1+\frac{\sigma_1^2}{2}}+(1-p)e^{\mu_2+\frac{\sigma_2^2}{2}}-1$.***

My question is : why I have different values for $\kappa$? Could some one explain for me where I am wrong ? thank you for your time.

Comment: The first part of your post is incorrect. The distribution of a mixture is not the distribution of a weighted sum.

Comment: Your second line is incorrect. $X$ has a _mixture_ normal distribution and not a normal distribution as the last equality on the second line asserts. Your calculation of the pdf of $Y$ as a mixture of log-normal distributions is correct; the statement made on line 3 is not.

Comment: Eupraxix1981: why is that ? so what is the distribution of $X$ ?  I found it here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables

Comment: Dilip : isn't if $Y\sim logNormal(\mu,\sigma^2)$ then $E(Y)=e^{\mu+0.5\sigma^2}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With $p$ denoting a constant in the interval $(0,1)$, suppose $X$ has density
$$f(x)=p\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right)+
(1-p)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)$$
which is a *mixture* density.  Then,
$$\begin{align}
F_X(\alpha) &= P\{X \leq \alpha\}\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha} f(x)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}p\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right)+
(1-p)\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= p\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx+(1-p)\int_{-\infty}^{\alpha}
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2}\right)\,\mathrm dx\\
&= p\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)
+(1-p)\Phi\left(\frac{\alpha-\mu_1}{\sigma_1}\right)\\
&\neq \Phi\left(\frac{\alpha-(p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2)}{\sqrt{p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2}}\right)
\end{align}$$

> In other words, **it is not true** (as you state on Line 3 of your question, and continue to assert dogmatically) that $X$ has a normal distribution with mean $p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2)$ and variance $p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2$.
>   That is,
>   $$X\sim N(p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2,p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2)\quad
> \mathbf{is~a~false~statement}$$

As a result, your calculation $\kappa=E(e^X)-1=e^{p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2+\frac{1}{2}(p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2)}-1$ is not correct.

Comment: Thanks Dilip :)) I got it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mu := p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2$ and $\sigma^2 := p^2\sigma_1^2 + (1-p)^2\sigma_2^2$. Then, one can show that, the pdf of $Y$ is:
$$g(y)=\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(\ln(y)-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right),$$
not the one that you display (your $Y$ presentation as linear combination of log-normal variables is wrong: if $X=pX_1 +(1-p)X_2$, then $Y={\rm e}^X = {\rm e}^{pX_1}{\rm e}^{(1-p)X_2}$, not $p{\rm e}^{X_1}+(1-p){\rm e}^{X_2}$; also, $f$, pdf of $X=pX_1+(1-p)X_2$, is NOT $pf_1 + (1-p)f_2$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are pdf's of $X_1$ and $X_2$; lastly, see Dilip Sarwarte comment on what is really your starting hypothesis on $X$ being normal variable, as say a linear combination of independent normal variables, or on its pdf being a mixture of normal pdf's).

Comment: But what you wrote is exactly   $X=N(p\mu_1+(1-p)\mu_2,p^2\sigma_1^2+(1-p)^2\sigma_2^2)$? I am confused now :((
Here is what I have 
Let $G(y)$ be the cdf of $Y$, then 
$G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(e^X<y)=p(x<ln(y))=F_X(ln(y))$
there fore $g(y)=f(ln(y))\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Yes. $Y={\rm e}^X$ and $X$ is normal with params $\mu$ and $\sigma^2$. Hence $Y$ is log-normal. Hence $g$ form.

Comment: Here is what I have 
Let $G(y)$ be the cdf of $Y$, then 
$G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(e^X<y)=p(X<ln(y))=F_X(ln(y))$
there fore $g(y)=f(ln(y))\frac{1}{y}$

Comment: Yes. Use $f$ (pdf of $X$) and get $g$.

Comment: Thanks Ir7 for replying. I meant by applying what I wrote, i showed that the pdf of $Y$ is given in the form I wrote in the post? Can you tell me where I AM WRONG ?

Comment: Note also that, if $X=pX_1 +(1-p)X_2$, then $Y={\rm e}^X = {\rm e}^{pX_1}{\rm e}^{(1-p)X_2}$, not $p{\rm e}^{X_1}+(1-p){\rm e}^{X_2}$.

Comment: I know that :))) but based on what you said then I must be wrong some where down here :

Let $G(y)$ be the cdf of $Y$, then 
$G(y)=P(Y<y)=P(e^X<y)=p(X<ln(y))=F_X(ln(y))$
there fore $g(y)=f(ln(y))\frac{1}{y}$
so 
the pdf  $g(y)$ of $Y$ is given by 

$g(y)=p\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp(-\frac{(ln(y)-\mu_1)^2}{2\sigma_1^2})+
(1-p)\frac{1}{y\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp(-\frac{(ln(y)-\mu_2)^2}{2\sigma_2^2})$

i.e $Y=p\times logNormal(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)+(1-p)\times logNormal(\mu_2,\sigma_1^2)$

where $logNormal(\mu_1,\sigma_1^2)$ means a log-normal distribution.

Comment: can you tell me where I am wrong ?

Comment: $f$, pdf of $X=pX_1+(1-p)X_2$, is NOT $pf_1 + (1-p)f_2$, where $f_1$ and $f_2$ are pdf's of $X_1$ and $X_2$.

Comment: In my proof, I don't need to write $X=pX_1 +(1-p)X_2$. I am sorry that I think I am not satisfied with your explanation :(((

Comment: @Nguyen That's ok. In my answer, I mentioned Dilip Sawarte's comment. Basically, if you stop claiming that $X$ is normal, then $f=pf_1+(1-p)f_2$, as given directly by the problem. Hence, your $g$ is correct. If you claim that $X$ is normal (with $\mu$ and $\sigma$), then my $g$ is correct.